# Magento 2 How can refresh minicart cache.After clear cart session and place order programmitically

Tags: magento2

[image]

How can resolve that issue .I remove all session

```
$this->_checkoutSession->clearQuote()->clearStorage();
    $this->_checkoutSession->clearQuote();
    $this->_checkoutSession->clearStorage();
    $this->_checkoutSession->clearHelperData();
    $this->_checkoutSession->resetCheckout();
    $this->_checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
```

Comment: Are you doing this call with Ajax?

Comment: Not i am not using ajax but i create order programmatic and own success page so give me advice what happens i try many cases every time cache maintained.

Comment: Please any one who solve that problem

Comment: Are you doing this with post request?

Comment: Not I create a order programmability 
Can you please tell me how can i fire request to update minicart sidebar in magent2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found that solution

For update minicart section first we create a `sections.xml` in `/etc/frontend/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="test/process/observer">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

And after apply Ajax on particular section phtml

And one more solution founded

```
require([
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });
```

Comment: We created quick view after product adding mini cart is updated how to update this ?

Comment: Create a secton.xml and define path of ajax modilename/controller/action  and update section cart on that

Comment: We created sections.xml 
    <action name="checkout/cart/add">
 <section name="cart"/>
    </action> but which file is ajax on particular section phtml i dont understand

Comment: Action means that url which you are using in ajax
and create section file in custom module for update cart on a particular action

Comment: It's ok when you call a particular action, but imagine you empty your cart through an observer. How to tell Magento to refresh the section ?

Comment: Answer to myself: do an horrible fake ajax call...

Comment: @PrinceYadav I am using Magento 2.1.4 and I have same issue,  Can you please share full fix. Thank you.

Comment: You can use

require([
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });

Comment: customerData is not defined error generated @PrinceYadav

Comment: customerData object of Magento_Customer/js/customer-data

Comment: @Prince Yadhav Greate answer working fine for me

Comment: I put this code in the following files and it works now:
app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/noItems.phtml
app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml